# python count function - got it working but cant work out the answers

Tags: count

i am getting answers to this that i dont understand

```
print('please enter numbers with commas (end with 0):')
num = input()
num.count(',')
print('You have entered ' + str(num.count('')) + ' numbers')
```

answers

```
please enter numbers with commas (end with 0):
5,3,0
You have entered 6 numbers

please enter numbers with commas (end with 0):
5, 2 , 0
You have entered 9 numbers
```

Comment: Why are you counting no spaces again?

Comment: The script is working as written:
`5,3,0\n` is indeed 6 character: `5` `,` `3` `,` `0` `\n`.  What are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, this is what you want

```
print('please enter numbers with commas (end with 0):')
num = input()
count = num.count(',')
print('You have entered ' + str(count) + ' numbers')
```